# Function overloading with shared pointer argument ambiguity

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, shared-ptr, overloading

I want to make overloaded functions that take a shared pointer to a base class and derived classes. It seems to work for references and raw pointers, but not for shared pointers in the case of an extra derived class. See the example code:

```
#include <memory>

class Base{};
class Derived : public Base {};
class ExtraDerived : public Derived {};


bool IsBase(Base*){ return true; }
bool IsBase(Derived*){ return false; }

bool IsBase(std::shared_ptr<Base>){ return true; }
bool IsBase(std::shared_ptr<Derived>){ return false; }

int main() 
{
    auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    auto extra_derived = std::make_shared<ExtraDerived>();
    // works
    auto raw_result_derived = IsBase(derived.get());
    auto raw_result_extra_derived = IsBase(extra_derived.get());
    auto shared_result_derived = IsBase(derived);
    // doesn't work
    auto shared_result_extra_derived = IsBase(extra_derived);
}
```

I get: "error C2668: 'IsBase' : ambiguous call to overloaded function" when using Visual Studio 2012, but I also get the same result when I try the code on here http://ideone.com/6uoa0p.

This doesn't seem like desired behaviour (as it works for 'raw' stuff). Is this a limitation of the templating, is there another reason why this doesn't work or is it a bug?
And how can I make it work in the least ugly way?

The best I can come up with is

```
//ugly workaround
bool IsBase(std::shared_ptr<Base>, Base*){ return true; }
bool IsBase(std::shared_ptr<Derived>, Derived*){ return false; }
template<typename T> bool IsBase(std::shared_ptr<T> input )
{
    return IsBase(input, input.get());
}
```

Comment: Why do you want that? Just only provide the base function, it will happily accept the derived class pointer. If you want to catch derived class objects, your method won't work anyway because it would need dispatch on the dynamic type of the function argument to be done right. If the programmer implicitly converts the `Ptr<Derived>` to a `Ptr<Base>` before passing, this overloading approach breaks down.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I didn't think of that situation. I might have to rethink what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a limitation of the templating, is there another reason why this doesn't work or is it a bug?

No, it is not a bug. Indeed it seems you've hit the only pitfall of smart pointers: an `std::shared_ptr<base>` can be constructed from `std::shared_ptr<derived>` as well as from `std::shared_ptr<extra_derived>`, but none of these two conversion sequences is better than the other (being two user-defined conversion sequences of the same length).

However, you can still fix your overloads by using some SFINAE constraints:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Selected for `std::shared_ptr<Base>`
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, Base>::value>::type* = nullptr>
bool IsBase(std::shared_ptr<T>){ return true; }

// Selected for `std::shared_ptr<T>` where T is a class derived from Base,
// but not Base itself
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value &&
    !std::is_same<T, Base>::value
    >::type* = nullptr>
bool IsBase(std::shared_ptr<T>){ return false; }
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work on VS2012, but it should in the future. It works for this simple case, but if I had more overloads for different derived classes it might become a problem. I'll have to think about whether I actually want to have functions like this or not considering the comment of JohannesSchaub-litb on my question.